# jQuery: set / reset form fields with certain class (improve code)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, find, show-hide

I am new to jQuery and hope someone here can help me with this.

I have a large HTML form with a **hidden div** (`'#requestDetails'`). 
Within this div there are checkboxes, radio buttons and selects with a certain class on a specific value (`'.hiddenDefault'`) which is used to only apply a default value when they are visible.

Now I have a certain event that shows this div and another one that hides it again.

**When showing the div** I want to set the above default values.
**When hiding it** I want to reset the fields, incl. all input fields within that div (i.e. uncheck / unselect them and remove any default or entered values).

I have the following code which looks ok to me at first glance but I would like to know if this is proper / valid code, if I am missing anything here and if there is a better / faster way to achieve the same.

**My jQuery:**

```
$('[name=requestType]').on('change', function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('triggerDiv')){
        $('#requestDetails').find('.hiddenDefault').each(function(){
            // set default values + show div
            $(this).not('select').prop('checked', true);
            $(this).not('input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio]').prop('selected', true);
        });
        $('#requestDetails').show();
    }else{
        $('#requestDetails').find('input, select').each(function(){
            // empty / reset fields + hide div
            $(this).find('input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio]').prop('checked', false);
            $(this).find('input').not(':button, :checkbox, :hidden, :radio, :reset, :submit').val('');
            $(this).find('select').prop('selected', false);                     
        });
        $('#requestDetails').hide();
    }
});
```

Many thanks in advance for any help with this, 
Mike

Comment: Try changing .prop('checked', true); to .attr('checked', true);

Comment: @Luca De Nardi: Thanks - isn't .prop the newer function ?

Comment: They look very similar, I'll investigate further. Meanwhile try check here the differences between them: http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: Thanks, Luca ! - My thought here was also if there is a way to somehow combine what I have in separate lines as I think in my code I am looping e.g. 3 times through all the fields when hiding them (one for each .find).

Comment: To set all of them at once you can also use $('#requestDetails input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', 'true')

Comment: you can use HTML to reset your the fields as in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dwtpcm8m/  then you can keep the first function to set defaults

Comment: What do you mean by 'reset'? Reset to the default state that these `<input>` elements had on page-load, or simply remove all `checked`, `selected` or otherwise entered values?

Comment: Thanks all ! - Just made some updates to the show part. @DavidThomas: in my case this is the same, so I need to uncheck any radio buttons and checkboxes, unselect any selects and empty any inputs there.

Comment: @DavidThomas right, your goal is to empty all fields, right? did you check the jsfiddle?

Comment: @Emm: Thanks - see my comment below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just improving syntax or style of code you have written:

```
$('[name=requestType]').on('change', function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('triggerDiv')){
        // show div + set default values
            $(this).not('select').prop('checked', true);
        $(this).not('input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio]').prop('selected', true);
            $('#requestDetails').show();
    }else{
        // hide div + reset fields
             $('#requestDetails').find('input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio], input, select').not(':button, :checkbox, :hidden, :radio, :reset, :submit').val('').prop('checked', false);             
             $('#requestDetails').hide();
    }
});
```

Sorry have not checked syntax, so correct me if I am wrong at it.
Not this will  improve performance as well as you have written inside each.

Comment: @Simple Man: Thanks a lot - that's exactly what I was looking for ! Can you update it to show the .not function I just added ? Will accept then as this is all I needed. :)

Comment: @Emm: Thanks - it doesn't look like this refers to the specific div and class that I need it to (as there are other hidden divs and fields on this form as well).

Comment: Is it giving you any error? I mean applying not will do the same thing I have done.

Comment: @SimpleMan: Thanks - I actually had to change it as my original show code didnt work correctly so I thought it would make sense to adapt the answer as well. :) Also, regarding your hide part, do I understand it right that you set the values of the checkboxes and radio to '' as well ? Is that on purpose ?

Comment: reset control type will reset its parent form.. here i updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dwtpcm8m/1/ to have 3 forms. you can read more here http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#idx-control-7

Comment: Updated as per your request